# Unable to loop through ggplot histogram

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to loop through every column of the iris data set and plot a histogram in ggplot. So I'm expecting 5 different histograms to appear. However, my for loop below returns nothing. How can I fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)

for (i in colnames(iris)){
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = i))+
    geom_histogram()
}
```

Comment: There is no need to load the entire `tidyverse` if the goal is to only use `ggplot`(2)

Comment: If you really want to do this with a for loop you might have to to use aes_string instead of aes. But for getting the desired results i think @Maurits Evers answer is the better approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `for` loop, the `tidyverse`/`ggplot` way would be to reshape the data from wide to long and then plot using `facet_wrap`

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
    gather(key, val, -Species) %>%
    ggplot(aes(val)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>% 
  gather(Mesure, Value, -Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(rows=vars(Species), cols=vars(Mesure))
```

Result:
[image]